# How to get commands usage in python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How can i get commands usage history from all server bot has been installed. I can't find any sample code for this in google search.

```
So for an example if we type !commands_stats

Bot reply's with {members.name} from {server.name} used !hello command.
```

It lists by top 10 or xx previous commands used in all server.

Otherwise if any members use commands in any server it should send a confirmation message for a specified channel id of mentioned server.

```
So for an example if a member from any server type !hello in channel.
after bot reply to that message it should send a confirmation to listed Server ID and Channel ID like below.

Bot reply's with {members.name} from {server.name} used !hello command.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Message class is one way of doing this as per the [documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message)

```
client = Botcommand_prefix=("!")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def hello(ctx):
    await client.say("Hi") 
    print(f"{ctx.message.author.name} from {ctx.message.server} used !hello command")
```

You could use these parameters to add values to a dictionary of all commands you have